# SRIOV support in netplan

Tags: server, netplan

I am using netplan nowadays and so far very happy with it but now i have question related `SRIOV` support.

To create SRIOV VF i am using this command at startup in `/etc/rc.local`

`# echo '7' > /sys/class/net/eth3/device/sriov_numvfs`

Does netplan support that kind of function to tell created number of VF on specific interface? I would like to keep all network configuration in one place instead of multiple file :)

Answer (score 3):

Netplan does support SRIOV since version 0.99. Ubuntu 20.04 has netplan 0.100 so it should work.

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to define the interfaces like this:

```
ethernets:
  ens10f0
    virtual-function-count: 7
  ens10f0v1:
    link: ens10f0
```

Where ens10f0 is the physical interface and ens10f0v1 is the first VF.

There is some documentation on this here: https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-ethernets%3A

Based on the configuration you provided in the comments I think you should try it like this

```
ethernets:
eno49:
  dhcp4: no
eno50:
  dhcp4: no
  virtual-function-count: 8
eno50v1:
  link: eno50
  dhcp4: no
```

Comment: Testing now, i will get back to you :)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.

Comment: Document saying it required `sriov` what does that means? I do have sriov enabled in BIOS and its working all i need to create vf.

Comment: Oh wait it works when i `vf1` section here is the output, can you add this output in your answer incase if pastebin die - https://pastebin.com/rAu0eCFm

Comment: seeing one problem after reboot of system i have to run `netplan apply` to bring up all VF otherwise they are not up.

Comment: I tested this myself and got the same results. It worked with netplan apply but the interface didn't come up after a reboot. I turns out there was a bug in netplan that caused this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1890838

Comment: It works on my system after doing apt install netplan.io to upgrade from version 0.99 to version 0.100. Can you check if you have the latest version of netplan on your system?

Comment: Thanks, after upgrade it has solved reboot issue but now other issue pop up which is my `VF` nic name showing eth0, eth1, eth2... so on. in 0.99 version it was showing proper which was eno50v1, eno50v2, eno50v3...  did you see that issue ? - https://pastebin.com/UXWL34s5

Comment: No, I didn't see that issue.. I would try to make a section in your netplan config for each vf instead of the vf1 section you have. Like in the  example I put in the answer.

Comment: I can do static entries for each `VF` but that is not a good way because i have 64 vf and it will make my file damn longer, it would be great of netplan has some kind of `match` statement or `regex` to deal with this issue.  (In that case sticking with `echo '64' > /sys/class/net/eth3/device/sriov_numvfs` would be easier)