# Unable to create the file /sys/class/net/<device>/device/sriov_totalvfs file in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, 22.04, sudo, filesystem, root

I gave all permissions to all files and folders in /sys/ directory, but still I'm unable to create any file in the /sys/ directory too in Ubuntu 22.04. I'm trying to create an sr-iov interface, when I added configuration according to [SRIOV support in netplan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301123/sriov-support-in-netplan) but it is asking for the above file (mentioned in the title).